# Xcode 5 Play Movie using MPMoviePlayer returns SIGABRT

Tags: ios, xcode, mpmovieplayercontroller, sigabrt

I have been trying to play a local video file by clicking a UIButton and have continued to return SIGABRT errors every time I click the button in the simulator.  I have tried m4v and mp4 files.  Below is the latest set of code that I have tried and still returns SIGABRT.  This exact set of code seems to work for everyone on YouTube, but doesn't work when I run my app.  And yes...I did import the MediaPlayer Framework.  Is there something different about Xcode 5.1.1?

```
//  ViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

- (IBAction)playButton:(id)sender;

@end


//  ViewController.m
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end
@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)playButton:(id)sender
{
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"movie1" ofType:@"m4v"]];

MPMoviePlayerViewController *playerController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:playerController];
playerController.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;

[playerController.moviePlayer play];
playerController = nil;
}
```

Comment: I think you have an error in your nib or storyboard check if all connections are correct(IBOutlets & IBActions). Check fileURLWithPath: also it may be returning nil,also try replacing it with fileURLWithString

Comment: If u get any particular error in console, update the question with those errors.And y u use playerController = nil;.

Comment: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)       Does that mean anything?

Comment: Ok I can now get the video player to show after changing fileWithURLPath to URLWithString, but it will just continue to say loading forever.

Comment: I also had it so the video player would briefly display then disappear and give error "_itemFailedToPlayToEnd: {
    kind = 1;
    new = 2;
    old = 0;
}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
//ViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

- (IBAction)playButton;
@property MPMoviePlayerController *mpc;

@end

//ViewController.m
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize mpc;

- (IBAction)playButton
{
NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"videofile" ofType:@"mov"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:bundle];
mpc = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

[mpc setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeFile];

[[self view]addSubview:mpc.view];
[mpc setFullscreen:YES];

[mpc play];
}

@end
```